# Subdivide vector in equal bins and calculate the mean of each bin

Tags: r

I'd like the cut the following dataset in 10 equal bins of $Date to get equal samples. Than calculate the a mean and standard deviation of $Close of each of the 10 bins. I really don't know how to do this.

```
'data.frame':   1763 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date  : int  20080102 20080103 20080104 20080107 20080108 20080109 20080110 20080111 20080114 20080115 ...
 $ Open  : num  52.1 51.2 50 49.5 49.7 ...
 $ High  : num  52.3 51.5 50 50.1 49.7 ...
 $ Low   : num  50.8 50.2 48.7 48.6 47.8 ...
 $ Close : num  51 50.4 49.1 49.4 48 ...
 $ Volume: int  8053700 7753200 8501400 14031100 11721000 10971500 18732300
57219900 18554900 16955000 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut()` to divide `Date` into groups, then use `aggregate()` to aggregate over the groups. Supposing your data frame is called `df`:

```
with(df, aggregate(Close,
                   by = list(Date = cut(Date, 10, include.lowest = TRUE)),
                   FUN = function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))
```

This returns a data frame with three columns: the date bin, the mean of `Close` in that bin, and the standard deviation of `Close` in that bin.

It might be a good idea to convert your integer dates to the R date type first. To do that, try the following:

```
df <- transform(df, Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), "%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: I got this message:
`FUN = function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))
Error: Unexpected ')' in "FUN = function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x)))"`

Comment: @Niels: That's weird--the code works fine for me. Can you make sure everything is copied correctly on your end and try again? That last close paren should be closing `with()`, so if you've omitted `with()`, you'll need to drop the last paren.

Comment: It works fine now. But instead of 10 the code makes 8 bins. Is it possible to format the `$date` vector as time series?

Comment: @Niels: Again, the code works as expected for me; it makes the requested 10 bins. To create a time series, take a look at `?as.ts`.

Comment: result: `with(stock_AXP, aggregate(Close,
+                             by = list(Date = cut(Date, 10, include.lowest = TRUE)),
+                             .... [TRUNCATED] 
                     Date       x.1       x.2
1  [2.008e+07,2.0086e+07] 37.937549  9.638060
2 (2.0086e+07,2.0092e+07] 26.965357  9.190663
3 (2.0098e+07,2.0105e+07] 41.661865  2.406813
4 (2.0105e+07,2.0111e+07] 46.738000  2.503095
5 (2.0111e+07,2.0117e+07] 48.202913  2.520370
6 (2.0117e+07,2.0123e+07] 56.011600  2.765012
7 (2.0129e+07,2.0135e+07] 72.861349  7.897435
8 (2.0135e+07,2.0141e+07] 89.790714  3.137210
> `

Comment: @Niels: I don't understand why that's happening for you because I get 10 groups in every test I do. I included some code to convert your integer dates to the date type. Try running that first and then rerunning the aggregation and see if that helps anything.